# I want to put a new project on Github

Tags: github

I have a java/GWT project in eclipse , There is a Git repo git@github.com:example/example.git
where i want to put my complete project for the first time 
Please guide me how can i do this , I am new to Github 
I have searched a lot ,but couldn't able to do it successfully
I do have GIT Bash and GIT GUI

Thanks

Comment: http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/

Answer (score 0):

Note that instead of having a msysgit installation (`git bash` and `git gui`), you could install on Windows the new **[windows.guthub.com](http://windows.github.com/)**:

That will facilitate cloning that repo.

The other alternative is to declate and clone it through Egit within Git, as described in this tutorial: [Using Egit with GitHub](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html#github).
Note that Eclipse+Egit means you don't *have to* install a msysgit (it is still recommended though, to benefit from the rich CLI of git *outside* Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [setup](http://help.github.com/set-up-git-redirect/) and [create a repo](http://help.github.com/create-a-repo/) instructions on github itself.

Basically you're going to do the following:

1. Install git on your development pc.
2. [git init](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-init) to create a local git repository for your project.
3. [git add](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-add) your files to the local repository.
4. [git commit](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-commit) changes to the local repository.
5. [git push](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-push) to the remote github server when necessary.

Search Stack Overflow - try this post for starters: [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)